# Magento specific Categories are not displaying in layered Fiter Navigation

Tags: layered-navigation, category-products, magento1.9.3

I am working on a Magento website 1.9.3.7 and there is an issue in category display in navigation filter.

Only some category is displaying in layered navigation filter but newly categories are not displaying in the filter. Also, some old categories are not coming in the filter.

I have already followed all possible option which is necessary for the filter.

Please advise what could be the problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Provide snap for both category page then let u know what was the issue.

Comment: Please check your category page layout from Catalog -> Manage Categories -> Category Name -> Custom Design, And Select "2 columns with left bar"from "Page Layout".

And Make sure your category display setting "Is Anchor" to "Yes". http://prntscr.com/lkjuzs